# Как обработать кириллицу в POST запросе

Tags: php

Есть post запрос, в котором могут передаваться слова кириллицой. Как мне обработать этот запрос, чтобы кириллица отображалась нормально? 
Если юзать

```
header("Content-Type: text/html;charset=windows-1251");
```

То появляется об ошибке получения хеадера, т.к. там еще идет прием пост запроса от стороннего сервера. Как решить проблему, кто знает?

Comment: Проблемы вообще-то нет, если пост отдаётся корректно. Покажи как он формируется (не надо вываливать весь код, покажи только то, что не соответствует RFC)

Comment: Судя по вопросу, ТС не знает, что может не соответствовать RFC

Comment: Судя по вопросу, ТС не знает про заголовки. А, может быть и так (включаю телепата) юзает какой-то готовый код методом копипаста..

Comment: про RFC не знаю, но метод post.

Answer (score 2):

ПОСТ данные, как правило, кодируются в UTF-8.

Попробуйте: iconv('UTF-8', 'WINDOWS-1251', $_POST['variable']);

Comment: Смотря чем этот пост-запрос посылается..  Если через ajax, то точно utf-8, если просто форма, то кодировка соотвествует кодировке посылающей страницы

Comment: >ПОСТ данные, как правило,
Ссылку на правило дайте, pls.

Comment: Автор высказал проблему с кодировкой, логично было предположить, что используется аякс как минимум.

Comment: iconv('utf-8', 'windows-1251', $_REQUEST["var"]) - не помогло, точнее переменная == ''

Comment: @istem, прошу прощения. Какие там заголовки-шмаголовки, тут проблема куда глубже - "два равно" у нихъ...

Comment: Пробовал как и гет, так и пост - одно и то же. Насчет стороннего сервиса - робокасса, может кто сталкивался? Проверка success...